# Validation Rule error not showing in lwc near field even though error location specified

Tags: lightning-web-components, validation-rule, lightning-recordeditform

I have a validation rule error that fires when Defect__c has a value and DefectReason__c is blank. In the validation rule, I have set the error location to DefectReason__c. The error message shows near the top of page instead. What could be causing this? I'm certain that I have been able to have the error message display at the location of the field causing the error before.

```
<lightning-record-edit-form 
            record-id={inspection.Id} 
            object-api-name="Inspection__c"
            density="comfy"
            onsuccess={handleSuccess}
            onsubmit={handleSubmit}
            onerror={handleError}
            >

            <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Defect__c"></lightning-input-field>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="DefectReason__c"></lightning-input-field>
            </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

On click of submit button of the form invoke below function in controller.js

```js
validateFields() {
    this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field').forEach(element => {
        element.reportValidity();
    });
}
```

Comment: I got the same result. I tried it before and after the submit call: 
```javascript
    handleSubmit(event) {
        this.loaded=false;
        console.log('HANDLESUBMIT');
        //this.validateFields();
        this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit();
        this.validateFields();
    }
    validateFields() {
        this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field').forEach(element => {
            element.reportValidity();
        });
    }
```